# ASP.NET Core fail to create root certificate

Tags: asp.net-core

I just try fresh install docker on windows 10 pro with Hyper-V, and create new asp.net core 2.0 project, after VS2017 pull the docker image, I try to run the web project , however an error with - **Failed to create certificate**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bug https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/99

By this link you can find rows which you can delete from 'docker-compose.override.yml'

Comment: This works. Direct link to the workaround comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/99#issuecomment-391200602